# Difference between C# and VB.NET for default values of private members

Tags: c#, vb.net, default

In C# I have the following code:

1. a base class with a virtual InitClass() function
2. a child class which overrides the InitClass() function. In this function I set a private variable
3. a public property exposing my private field

   ```
   namespace InheritenceTest
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
               Console.WriteLine(childClass.SomeString);
               Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }

       public class BaseClass
       {
           public BaseClass()
           {
               InitClass();
           }

           protected virtual void InitClass()
           {
               // Do Nothing here
           }
       }

       public class ChildClass: BaseClass 
       {
           private string _someString = "Default Value";
           public ChildClass()
           { 
           }

           protected override void InitClass()
           {
               base.InitClass();
               _someString = "Set in InitClass()";
           }

           public string SomeString
           {
               get { return _someString; }
               set { _someString = value; }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The Console output from this program is "Set in InitClass()".

Now I converted this piece of code to VB.NET.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text

Namespace InheritenceTest
    Module Program
        Public Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
            Dim childClass As New ChildClass()
            Console.WriteLine(childClass.SomeString)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub
    End Module

    Public Class BaseClass
        Public Sub New()
            InitClass()
        End Sub

        Protected Overridable Sub InitClass()
            ' Do Nothing here 
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class ChildClass
        Inherits BaseClass
        Private _someString As String = "Default Value"
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub InitClass()
            MyBase.InitClass()
            _someString = "Set in InitClass()"
        End Sub

        Public Property SomeString() As String
            Get
                Return _someString
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _someString = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The output of this VB.NET program is "Default Value".

When looking at the code while debugging (the VB.NET code) you see that when the constructor finished doing it's job, the default Value is set, while for C# it's the other way around (first the default value is set, than the constructor is called).

Can anyone explain me why this is the case? And which of the 2 languages is "correct"?

Answer (score 5):

The 2 languages simply differ in the way they approach this particular problem.

As to why this is done the way it is in C#, you should check out Eric's blog series on the subject

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx

As to the why in VB.Net.  I'm not entirely sure why VB.Net chose this particular approach.  My off the cuff guess would be a VB6 compatability issue but I'm not even sure if VB6 had similar scenarios.

Comment: The vb.net approach allows field initializers to make reference to the object under construction.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @JaredPar

The only reason VB.NET different initialization scheme is because VB was designed like this since past, if they would change this sequence in VB.NET, programmers migrating from VB to VB.NET will have difficultly as well as some compatibility issues may arise as you are still able to import most of your old VB code into VB.NET